# Error when running struts2 via tomcat (errors include "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker..."

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, netbeans, struts2

I'm brand new to Java and struts2 - I've written a test app that will capture information from the user (3 fields), store the information to mysql, and then display the information in a table if the save is successful (at least I think this is what I've written.

I'm feeling pretty lost - I have tried to search for the resolution to my issue but am unsure of which way to look first... any assistance would be beneficial!

I'm using: Netbeans 7.3.1, tomcat 7, jdk 1.7, mysql, struts2...

Here are the errors I'm receiving upon run in netbeans...

```
PackageName (run):

compile-jsps:
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
In-place deployment at .../packageName/build/web
deploy?config=file%3A%2Fvar%2Ffolders%2Fjz%2Fbtt5nc_x5l3g29r_g7c8f3yc0000gn%2FT%2Fcontext1380170394207520336.xml&path=/Jive_OSInfo_NB
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /packageName but context failed to start
...packageName/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1039: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 11 seconds)



Apache Tomcat Log:

Sep 26, 2013 10:38:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 26, 2013 10:38:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 26, 2013 10:38:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@28f9ed78')
Sep 26, 2013 10:38:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file: .../build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.4.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:450)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1461)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file: .../build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.4.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - jar:file: .../build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.4.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:239)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:156)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - jar:file: ~/tomcat/lib/struts2-core-2.3.15.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - jar:file: .../build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.4.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:223)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: yep sorry - accidentally hit enter and the whole thing (sans code) saved...

Comment: Maven is your project doctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got two versions of the same jar on the classpath:

- `struts2-core-2.3.15.1`
- `struts2-core-2.3.4`

The error message tells you that both of these jars contain `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory`.

To resolve your issue, you'll have to remove one of these versions (probably the 2.3.4) from the classpath.  How to do that depends on how you're running the webapp and container.  If it's a standard Tomcat 7 deployment, your duplicate jar could appear in your war (under WEB-INF/lib) or also in Tomcat's /lib directory if you put it there.

Comment: Can't both jars contain the `ObjectFactory`? And what do you mean by the *standard* deployment?

Comment: By standard Tomcat deployment, I mean download Tomcat, unzip it and run it (vs running it from Eclipse, or NetBeans, or embedded).  Since there weren't any details as to how ea0723 is running Tomcat, I took a guess to provide an example of how one might go about solving the issue.  And can both jars contain the ObjectFactory?  Sure, they both physically could (and do)... but then you get this error.  Struts is enforcing that there can only be one on the classpath.

Comment: Do you mean that Eclipse or Netbeans run the Tomcat server embedded? Also, could you elaborate on how Struts is doing so, if any?

Comment: Thanks, Mark - I'll give your suggestion a try...

I originally ran Tomcat direct from terminal, but in this instance, it is running via Netbeans.

Comment: PS - if I just "build" the app, it completes without errors. I only get errors if I attempt to "run" from within Netbeans.

Comment: Thanks, Mark S - that answered this error... onto the next :)

Answer (score 1):

Found two struts jar at target location lib folder.

Reason: One jar has beencopied from local WEB-INF/lib folder and another copied from the pom.xml defined version(download) jar. 
Please remove jar from local folder. so that pom.xml will automatically download.

this solution will help.